# How to share data between vue components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm not a javascript developer, my job is to wire up the API's I built to some front end code written in vuejs by a 3rd party. I'm trying to access the 'shopping cart' to send details to a server. I'm having a hard time determining what is the child or parent. The flow is as follows:

- A. Select a concession
- B. Select an item to add to cart
- C. go to cart
- D. Checkout

This is the Product card

```
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col flex-wrap justify-center items-center w-1/3 px-12">
        <img :src="require(`../../assets/images/` + backgroundImg)" :alt="product.id"> 
        <h5 class="font-bold text-lg mt-2">{{ product.title }}</h5>
        <p class="text-15px text-gray-500 ">{{ product.short }}</p>
        <p class="text-15px text-gray-500 px-8">{{ product.long }}</p>
        <p class="text-base font-bold">${{ formatPrice(product.price) }}</p>
        <Button @click.native="$emit('add-cart', product)"  msg="Add to Cart" class="bg-seafoam rounded-md lg:text-sm lg:px-8 text-white mt-1"></Button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Button from '../Button.vue';

export default {
    name: 'ProductCard',
    components: {
        Button
    },
    props: {
        product: Object
    },
    data() {
        return {
            backgroundImg: this.product.image,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        formatPrice(value) {
        let val = (value/1).toFixed(2)
        return val.toLocaleString("en", {useGrouping: false, minimumFractionDigits: 2,})
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

---

This is the Product List code

```
     <template>
            <div>
                <span v-if="!hideMenu">
                    <MenuHero v-if="!viewCart" :locationName="locationName" :selectedVendor="selectedVendor" />
                </span>
                <CartHero v-if="viewCart" />
                <CheckoutHero v-if="showCheckout" />
                <div class="lg:px-40 pt-4 pb-16 m-auto max-w-" :class="{ 'bg-bgBlue': showCheckout, 'max-w-screen-2xl': !showCheckout }">
                    <div v-if="!hideBreadcrumb" class="breadcrumbs flex mb-6 ml-6">
                        <a href="/OrderResturantPicker" class="text-left mt-6 mb-12 lg:pl-0 text-sm lg:text-base bg-arrowRight font-bold text-darkBlueText bg-no-repeat bg-right bg-5px lg:bg-8px pr-3 lg:pr-6">Choose Restaurant</a>
                        <a @click="viewCart = false" class="text-left mt-6 mb-12 text-sm lg:text-base bg-arrowRight font-bold text-darkBlueText bg-no-repeat bg-right bg-5px lg:bg-8px pr-3 lg:pr-6 pl-1 lg:pl-4" >Choose Meal</a>
                        <a v-if="viewCart" class="breadcrumb text-left mt-6 mb-12 text-sm lg:text-base font-bold text-darkBlueText bg-no-repeat bg-right bg-5px lg:bg-8px pr-3 lg:pr-6 pl-1 lg:pl-4">View Cart</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-wrap section-wrapper">
                        <div v-if="!hideMenu" class="flex flex-wrap section-wrapper">
                            <div v-for="product in menu" :key="product.id" v-show="!viewCart" :class="{ sectionTitle: product.section }" class="flex flex-col w-full lg:mb-0 mb-6 lg:w-1/3">
                                <div v-if="product.section" class="text-left w-full text-darkBlueText lg:text-xl font-bold">{{ product.section }}</div>
                                <ProductCard @add-cart="addToCart(product)" :product="product" class="locationOption w-full flex py-2 px-6 lg:py-2 rounded-sm rounded-b-none text-gray-600 lg:text-lg md:text-base text-13px text-center cursor-pointer" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <CartList :cart="cart" v-if="viewCart" @show-checkout="showCheckoutScreen()" :totalPrice="totalPrice" :product="product"/>
                        <CartWidget :cart="cart" v-if="!viewCart && showCartWidget" :itemCount="itemCount" @view-cart="viewCart = !viewCart" :totalPrice="totalPrice"/>
                        <Checkout :cart="cart" :product="product" :totalPrice="totalPrice" v-if="showCheckout" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
        
        <script>
        import ProductCard from './ProductCard'
        import CartList from './TheCartList'
        import CartWidget from './CartWidget'
        import Checkout from './Checkout'
        import MenuHero from '../heros/MenuHero'
        import CartHero from '../heros/CartHero'
        import CheckoutHero from '../heros/CheckoutHero'
        
        export default {
            name: 'ProductList',
            components: {
                MenuHero,
                CartHero,
                CheckoutHero,
                ProductCard,
                CartList,
                CartWidget,
                Checkout,
                
            },
            props: {
                menu: Array,
                locationName: String,
                selectedVendor: String,
        
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    cart: [],
                    showCartWidget: false,
                    itemCount: 0,
                    totalPrice: 0,
                    viewCart: false, 
                    showCheckout: false,
                    hideMenu: false,
                    hideBreadcrumb: false,
                }
            },
            methods: {
                
                calculateTotal(item) {
                    this.totalPrice += item.price
                },
                addToCart(product) {
                    if(this.cart.includes(product)){
                        product.quantity++
                        
                        this.itemCount++
                        this.calculateTotal(product)
                    } else {
                        this.cart.push(product)
                        this.itemCount++
                        this.calculateTotal(product)
                        this.showCartWidget = true
                    }
                }, 
                showCheckoutScreen() {
                    this.showCheckout = true
                    this.viewCart = false
                    this.showCartWidget = false
                    this.hideMenu = true
                    this.hideBreadcrumb = true
                }
            },
        }
        </script>

----------
This is the cart list code

    <template>
        <div class="w-full">
            <div class="cart-heading-wrapper flex justify-between text-darkBlueText lg:text-xl font-bold">
                <h5 class="w-1/3 text-left">Item Name</h5>
                <h5 class="w-1/3 text-center ml-2 pl-16">Quantity</h5>
                <h5 class="w-1/3 text-right">Item Price</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="grid border-b border-gray-400">
                <div v-for="product in cart" :key="product.id" class="py-4 border-t border-gray-400">
                    <CartCard :product="product" :totalPrice="totalPrice" @incremented="calculateTotal(product)" @decremented="decrementTotal(product)" class="locationOption w-full flex py-2 lg:py-2 rounded-sm rounded-b-none text-gray-600 lg:text-lg md:text-base text-13px text-center cursor-pointer" />
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="flex flex-col justify-start float-right">
                <div class="mb-4 px-28 mt-8 flex justify-between"><span class="mr-24 text-xl text-darkBlueText font-bold">Tax:</span><span class="text-2xl text-darkBlueText font-bold">${{taxes}}</span></div>
                <div class="mb-4 px-28 flex justify-between"><span class="mr-24 text-xl text-darkBlueText font-bold">Fees:</span><span class="text-2xl text-darkBlueText font-bold">${{ fees }} </span></div>
                <div class="border-t border-gray-500 mb-12 px-28 pt-4 flex justify-between"><span class="mr-24 text-2xl text-darkBlueText font-bold">Total:</span><span class="text-2xl text-darkBlueText font-bold">${{ formatPrice(totalPrice) }}</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-full flex justify-between">
                <div class="flex flex-col">
                    <button class="py-2 px-16 mb-2 bg-white border-2 border-darkBlueText text-darkBlueText text-lg font-bold">Back to Menu</button>
                    <a class="underline" href="#">Browse Restaurants </a>
                </div>
                <span>
                    <button class="px-6 py-3 text-white font-bold bg-seafoam rounded-sm text-lg" @click="$emit('show-checkout')">Proceed To Checkout</button>
                </span>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import CartCard from './CartCard';
    
    export default {
        name: 'CartList',
        components: {
            CartCard,
        },
        props: {
            cart: Array,
            totalPrice: Number,
            product: Object,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                taxes: 0,
                fees: 0,
                grandTotal: 0,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            formatPrice(value) {
            let val = (value/1).toFixed(2)
            return val.toLocaleString("en", {useGrouping: false, minimumFractionDigits: 2,})
            },
    
            calculateTotal(item) {
                this.totalPrice += item.price
            },
    
            decrementTotal(item) {
                this.totalPrice -= item.price
            },
        },
    }
    </script>
```

---

Cart Widget Code

```
<template>
    <div class="translateCenter left-1/2 m-auto w-1/2 max-w-5xl py-5 px-6 border flex justify-between bg-white fixed bottom-10 border-black rounded-md">
        <div class="font-bold flex items-center">
            <div class="bg-cartImage w-7 h-7 mr-2 font-bold bg-no-repeat bg-cover text-15px bg-right pr-5"></div>
            {{ itemCount }} Item(s)
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center flex-grow ml-16">
            <div class="rounded-full bg-black h-3 w-3 mr-4"></div>
            <div class="flex items-center pt-px">
                <strong class="mr-2">Total:</strong> ${{ formatPrice(totalPrice) }}
            </div>
          
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <div @click="$emit('view-cart')" class="bg-arrowRight font-bold bg-no-repeat bg-8px text-15px bg-right pr-5">View Cart</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "CartWidget",
    props: {
        cart: Array,
        itemCount: Number,
        totalPrice: Number,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            total: 0,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        formatPrice(value) {
        let val = (value/1).toFixed(2)
        return val.toLocaleString("en", {useGrouping: false, minimumFractionDigits: 2,})
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

---

The Cart Card Code

```
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col flex-wrap justify-center items-center w-1/3">
        <div class="flex justify-between items-center w-full">
            <div class="flex w-1/3">
                <img class="w-32 h-32" :src="require(`../../assets/images/` + backgroundImg)" :alt="product.id">
                <div class="flex flex-col justify-center ml-4 text-left">
                    <h5 class="mb-4 text-xl text-darkBlueText font-bold">{{ product.title }}</h5>
                    <p class="text-15px text-gray-500 leading-5">{{ product.short }}</p>
                    <p class="text-15px text-gray-500 leading-5 whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden block w-3/4">{{ product.long }}</p>
                </div> 
            </div>
           
            <Quantity class="font-bold" :product="product" :totalPrice="totalPrice" @incremented="incremented()" @decremented="decremented()" />
            <p class="font-bold">${{ formatPrice(product.price) }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Quantity from './Quantity';

export default {
    name: 'ProductCard',
    components: {
        Quantity
    },
    props: {
        product: Object,
        totalPrice: Number
    },
    data() {
        return {
            backgroundImg: this.product.image,
            cart: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        formatPrice(value) {
        let val = (value/1).toFixed(2)
        return val.toLocaleString("en", {useGrouping: false, minimumFractionDigits: 2,})
        },
        incremented() {
            this.$emit('incremented')
        },
        decremented() {
            this.$emit('decremented')
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

---

And the Checkout Code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="apply-wrapper bg-bgBlue lg:p-32 lg:pt-12">
        <div class="form-wrapper  lg:bg-white rounded-2xl bg-bgBlue py-6 px-8 lg:py-12 lg:px-32 lg:shadow-lg max-w-screen-2xl m-auto">
            <form class="lg:flex flex-wrap m-auto">
                <h4 class="text-darkBlueText text-center text-xl font-bold mb-12 w-full">Contact and Delivery Information</h4>
                <div class="mb-8 lg:mb-4 text-left text-lg lg:text-xl lg:w-1/2 lg:pr-12">
                    <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
                    <input v-model="firstName" class="mt-2 h-8 lg:h-10 appearance-none border rounded border-black w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-700 text-sm leading-tight" id="firstname" type="text" name="FirstName" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-7 lg:mb-4 text-left text-lg lg:text-xl lg:w-1/2 lg:pl-12">
                    <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input v-model="lastName" class="mt-2 h-8 lg:h-10 text-sm appearance-none rounded border border-black w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-700 mb-3 leading-tight" id="lastname" type="text" name="LastName" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-8 lg:mb-4 text-left text-lg lg:text-xl lg:w-1/2 lg:pr-12">
                    <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                    <input v-model="phone" class="mt-2 h-8 lg:h-10 lg:mt-1 appearance-none rounded border border-black w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-700 text-sm leading-tight" id="phonenumber" type="tel" name="PhoneNumber" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-8 lg:mb-4 text-left text-lg lg:text-xl lg:w-1/2 lg:pl-12">
                    <label for="EmailAddress">Email Address</label>
                    <input v-model="email" class="mt-2 h-8 lg:h-10 lg:mt-1 appearance-none rounded border border-black w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-700 text-sm leading-tight" id="emailaddress" type="email" name="EmailAddress" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-8 lg:mb-4 inline-block text-left text-lg lg:text-xl w-1/2 pr-2 lg:pr-12">
                    <label for="Terminal" class="whitespace-nowrap">Terminal</label>
                    <input v-model="terminal" class="mt-2 h-8 lg:h-10 lg:mt-1 text-sm appearance-none rounded border border-black w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-700 mb-3 leading-tight" id="terminal" type="text" name="Terminal" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-8 lg:mb-4 inline-block text-left text-lg lg:text-xl w-1/2 pl-2 lg:pl-12">
                    <label for="Gate">Gate</label>
                    <input v-model="gate" class="mt-2 h-8 lg:h-10 lg:mt-1 text-sm appearance-none rounded border border-black w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-700 mb-3 leading-tight" id="gate" type="text" name="Gate" required>
                </div>

                <div class="w-1/2 m-auto">
                    <div class="mb-8 lg:mb-4 inline-block text-left text-lg lg:text-xl w-1/2 pl-2 lg:pl-12">
                        <label for="Tip">Leave A Tip?</label>
                        <currency-input v-model="tip" id="leaveATip" currency="USD" name="Tip" class="mt-2 h-8 lg:h-10 lg:mt-1 text-sm appearance-none rounded border border-black w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-700 mb-3 leading-tight" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="DeliveryDate" class="block w-full">When Should We Deliver?</label>
                        <input v-model="date" type="date" id="DeliveryDateTime" name="DeliveryDate"
                            value="Today"
                            min="2021-01-01" max="2040-12-31" required>
                        <input v-model="time" type="time" id="delTime" name="DeliveryTime"
                            min="00:00" max="23:59" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- stripe div -->
                
                <section class="row payment-form">
                    <h5 class="#e0e0e0 grey lighten-4">
                        Payment Method
                        <span class="right">$25</span>
                    </h5>

                    <div class="error red center-align white-text"> {{stripeValidationError}}</div>

                        <div class="col s12 card-element">
                            <label>Card Number</label>
                            <div id="card-number-element" class="input-value"></div>
                        </div>

                    <div class="col s6 card-element">
                        <label>Expiry Date</label>
                        <div id="card-expiry-element"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col s6 card-element">
                        <label>CVC</label>
                        <div id="card-cvc-element"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col s12 place-order-button-block">
                        <button class="btn col s12 #e91e63 pink" @click="placeOrderButtonPressed">Place Order</button>
                    </div>
                </section>
                
                <CartList :cart="cart" v-if="viewCart" :totalPrice="totalPrice" :product="product"/> 
            
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ProductList from "./ProductList";

export default {
    name: 'Checkout',
    components: {
        ProductList,
    },
    props: {
        cart: Array
    },
    data(){
       console.log("[DEBUG 1]: " + this.cart + " " + this.cart.product.id + " " + this.cart.product.short);
        return {
            viewCart: true,
            stripe: null,
            cardNumberElement:null,
            cardExpiryElement:null,
            cardCVCElement:null,
            stripeValidationError:null,
            firstName:'',
            lastName:'',
            phone:'',
            email:'',
            terminal:'',
            gate:'',
            tip:'',
            amount:25,
        }
        
    },
    mounted(){
        this.stripe = new Stripe("MY_KEY");
        this.init();
        this.testCart();
    },
    methods: {
        testCart(){
            console.log("[DEBUG 3]: " + this.cart + " " + this.cart.product.id + " " + this.cart.product.short);
            this.cart.printCart();
        },

        init(){
            // invoke and mount
            var elements = this.stripe.elements();

            this.cardNumberElement = elements.create("cardNumber");
            this.cardNumberElement.mount("#card-number-element");

            this.cardExpiryElement = elements.create("cardExpiry");
            this.cardExpiryElement.mount("#card-expiry-element");

            this.cardCVCElement = elements.create("cardCvc");
            this.cardCVCElement.mount("#card-cvc-element");
            
            // change events
            this.cardNumberElement.on("change", this.setValidationError);
            this.cardExpiryElement.on("change", this.setValidationError);
            this.cardCVCElement.on("change", this.setValidationError);
            
        },
        setValidationError(event){
            this.stripeValidationError = event.error ? event.error.message : "";
        },
        async processToken(data){
            const response = await fetch('https://asite.azurewebsites.net/api/payment', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept':'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            });
            const content = await response;
            console.log(content);

            if(content[2] === "True")
            {
                // success
                // create a new swift oder
                // how do I get access to the cart?
            }
        },
        placeOrderButtonPressed(){
            
            this.stripe.createToken(this.cardNumberElement).then(result => {
                if(result.error){
                    this.stripeValidationError = result.error.message;
                } 
                else {
                    var json = {
                        amount: this.amount,
                        source: result.token.id
                    }
                    this.processToken(json);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

</script>
```

---

I want to access items that are in the cart so I can make a post call to the server. But I can't seem to make that happen.

I don't need to show the items on the screen or anything. I simply want access to the cart which seems to be an array of items with a total.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

BTW Product is an object with an id, title, short description, long description, price, and default quantity of 1.

Comment: Whenever you show code you should create a [mcve]. While it might fulfill the criteria of being complete, and verifiable it is most certainly not minimal. Most of the shown code is likely, not relevant to illustrate the problem. having minimal code makes it easier for others to find the actual problem.

Comment: And some additional note about minimal and `I'm not a javascript developer, my job is to wire up the API's I built to some front end code written in vuejs by a 3rd party.`. That part of your question implies that you work for someone to create this. If that is true, you should make sure that you are allowed to post that code in its completeness to StackOverflow, code you posted here is available under `Creative Commons`, and that might not be what the owner of the code wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cart` is defined in your `ProductList`. You implement all other components inside of this component therefore it is the parent. It can distribute the items in the cart to all other components by adding the `:cart="cart"` property. In order for the child components to access it, they merely need to declare `cart` in the props they receive:

```
props: {
  cart: Array
}
```

Then you can access `this.cart` within the child component.

Comment: forgive my ignorance.... I imported the ProductList.vue and added the cart to my props in Checkout.vue. I logged to the console the cart but it shows as undefined, even after adding an item to the cart.  I must be missing something here.

Comment: @Mateo Can you update your code with the new attempt you've made? `<Checkout :cart="cart" />` within the `ProductList.vue` file (which defines `{ data () { return { ... cart :[] }}` should give you the access to `cart` within the `Checkout` component as long as the `props` definition from my answer is declared within the `Checkout` component

Comment: I have updated the code in Product list with the Checkout tag. The props in checkout has the cart array. I do get an Object in console log. But the members of the product such as it's id, title, short, and long description are undefined. let me know if I need push up another component.